# How to compute word scores in Scrabble using MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, indexing, ascii

I have a homework program I have run into a problem with.  We basically have to take a word (such as MATLAB) and have the function give us the correct score value for it using the rules of Scrabble.  There are other things involved such as double word and double point values, but what I'm struggling with is converting to ASCII. I need to get my string into ASCII form and then sum up those values. We only know the bare basics of strings and our teacher is pretty useless. I've tried converting the string into numbers, but that's not exactly working out. Any suggestions?

```
function[score] = scrabble(word, letterPoints)

doubleword = '#';
doubleletter = '!';
doublew = [findstr(word, doubleword)]
trouble = [findstr(word, doubleletter)] 
word = char(word)
gameplay = word;
ASCII = double(gameplay)


score = lower(sum(ASCII));
```

Comment: Usually with Scrabble there is some legend that tells you how many points are associated with each letter.  I don't see that in your code.  Are you given this, or do you have to also code this yourself?

Comment: @rayryeng we're given it. We have to upload it and then run our code to test it.

Comment: OK, so what exactly do you need help with? Do you want help in computing the score of the word?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes please. I figured once I converted it, the value should be correct. Then I could go on and deal with double letters and whatnot, but that's not quite the case. I tried doing upper instead of lower (since those are lower ASCII values, but that's not what it wants either)

Comment: I'll write an answer soon.  This requires that I reconstruct the point scoring table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building on Francis's post, what I would recommend you do is create a lookup array.  You can certainly convert each character into its ASCII equivalent, but then what I would do is have an array where the input is the ASCII code of the character you want (with a bit of modification), and the output will be the point value of the character.  Once you find this, you can sum over the points to get your final point score.

I'm going to leave out double points, double letters, blank tiles and that whole gamut of fun stuff in Scrabble for now in order to get what you want working.  By consulting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions), this is the point distribution for each letter encountered in Scrabble.

- 1 point: A, E, I, O, N, R, T, L, S, U
- 2 points: D, G
- 3 points: B, C, M, P
- 4 points: F, H, V, W, Y
- 5 points: K
- 8 points: J, X
- 10 points: Q, Z

What we're going to do is convert your word into lower case to ensure consistency.  Now, if you take a look at the letter `a`, this corresponds to ASCII code 97.  You can verify that by using the `double` function we talked about earlier:

```
>> double('a')

97
```

As there are 26 letters in the alphabet, this means that going from `a` to `z` should go from 97 to 122.  Because MATLAB starts indexing arrays at 1, what we can do is subtract each of our characters by 96 so that we'll be able to figure out the numerical position of these characters from 1 to 26.

Let's start by building our lookup table.  First, I'm going to define a whole bunch of strings.  Each string denotes the letters that are associated with each point in Scrabble:

```
string1point = 'aeionrtlsu';
string2point = 'dg';
string3point = 'bcmp';
string4point = 'fhvwy';
string5point = 'k';
string8point = 'jx';
string10point = 'qz';
```

Now, we can use each of the strings, convert to `double`, subtract by 96 then assign each of the corresponding locations to the points for each letter.  Let's create our lookup table like so:

```
lookup = zeros(1,26);
lookup(double(string1point) - 96) = 1;
lookup(double(string2point) - 96) = 2;
lookup(double(string3point) - 96) = 3;
lookup(double(string4point) - 96) = 4;
lookup(double(string5point) - 96) = 5;
lookup(double(string8point) - 96) = 8;
lookup(double(string10point) - 96) = 10;
```

I first create an array of length 26 through the [`zeros`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) function.  I then figure out where each letter goes and assign to each letter their point values.

Now, the last thing you need to do is take a string, take the lower case to be sure, then convert each character into its `ASCII` equivalent, subtract by 96, then sum up the values.  If we are given... say... MATLAB:

```
stringToConvert = 'MATLAB';
stringToConvert = lower(stringToConvert);
ASCII = double(stringToConvert) - 96;
value = sum(lookup(ASCII));
```

Lo and behold... we get:

```
value =

 10
```

The last line of the above code is crucial.  Basically, `ASCII` will contain a bunch of indexing locations where each number corresponds to the numerical position of where the letter occurs in the alphabet.  We use these positions to look up what point / score each letter gives us, and we sum over all of these values.

## Part #2

The next part where double point values and double words come to play can be found in my other StackOverflow post here:

[Calculate Scrabble word scores for double letters and double words MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943095/multipling-and-adding-to-final-output-in-matlab)

Comment: So I can follow that. You made up your array and then allowed MATLAB to index it in order to follow what it needs. My issue is that, I already have the letterPoints given to me in a file I have to load. So I can't exactly do the whole indexing ordeal. Is there a way for me to open up the file given? It only lets me load it. I can't see the point values :/

Comment: @JessicaMarie - Can you put the code required to load in this point system?  How exactly are these points loaded in?

Comment: It was explained very nicely :)

Comment: @JessicaMarie - Thanks!  That skill came from my previous job :) Starting out learning programming is never easy.  Trust me... I know.  The best thing you can do is just keep practicing.  It will click very soon!

Answer (score 1):

### Convert from string to ASCII:

```
>> myString = 'hello, world';
>> ASCII = double(myString)

ASCII =

   104   101   108   108   111    44    32   119   111   114   108   100
```

### Sum up the values:

```
>> total = sum(ASCII)

total =

        1160
```

The MATLAB help for `char()` says (emphasis added):

> S = char(X) converts array X of nonnegative integer codes into a character array. Valid codes range from 0 to 65535, where codes 0 through 127 correspond to 7-bit ASCII characters. The characters that MATLAB® can process (other than 7-bit ASCII characters) depend upon your current locale setting. **To convert characters into a numeric array, use the double function.**

ASCII chart [here](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/files/ascii.htm).

Comment: Kind-of, but if I put in like MATLAB and matlab, they have to give me the same value. That and when I try to do the ASCII = double(myString), it makes a complaint about matrix dimensions.

Comment: @JessicaMarie - Capital letters and small letters have different ASCII values.  If you do `double('MATLAB')` and `double('matlab');` you will get different results.  As such, you need to either figure out whether you want upper case or lower case letters only, or if you want to accept both and this is actually part of your program.

Comment: @JessicaMarie You can use the `lower()` function to convert strings from uppercase to lowercase. See also `upper()`. If the `double()` function is giving you a matrix dimension error, you might want to check to see if you are passing it a 2D matrix or a 1D matrix. Care to post your code?

Comment: @rayryeng That's one of the catches. It's for a scrabble game. MATLAB and matlab in scrabble would still have a point value of 10. I can't get the double function to work either, but I'm trying to helpdouble that problem.

Comment: @JessicaMarie - Do what Francis suggested and convert your letters to either all upper case, or all lower case.  Use `lower` or `upper`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html and http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/upper.html

Comment: @FrancisHarbison
Don't judge. I'm trying.
function[score] = scrabble(word, letterPoints)

doubleword = '#';
doubleletter = '!';
double = [findstr(word, doubleword)]
trouble = [findstr(word, doubleletter)]
word = char(word)
gameplay = word;
ASCII = double(gameplay)


score = lower(sum(ASCII));

Comment: @JessicaMarie - Can you show us what code you're doing to generate this error?  Go ahead and edit your post.  BTW, even though you're being forced to learn MATLAB, it's a beautiful language :)  Most of my reputation points come from answering MATLAB questions!

Comment: @JessicaMarie Not judging I would like to see some code to help, is all.

Comment: @JessicaMarie - Yup. Not judging.  We're here to help.

Comment: @rayryeng MATLAB wouldn't be so bad if the teacher actually taught us something lol I have no programming experience and this stuff isn't exactly in either of the books I have

Comment: @JessicaMarie - ahaha I hear you.  I actually used to teach MATLAB at my university before I graduated.

Comment: @rayryeng Used to teach, which means you got out of it haha
I appreciate all the help btw. I'm attempting to learn this stuff for real. In case I actually need to use it somewhere in life

Comment: @JessicaMarie - I liked teaching, but I wanted real world experience and become a licensed engineer.  I never said I didn't like it.  In any case, I'll write an answer.

Comment: @JessicaMarie - Your code isn't working because you are making a variable called `double`.  As such, you are shadowing over the function with a variable.  You need to call your variable something else.

Comment: @rayryeng Wow. I didn't even catch that. I'm still getting the same answer I did before I converted to ASCII values though. It's absurdly large. 433 :/

Comment: @JessicaMarie - That's because you are summing over the pure ASCII values.  What I would do given your experience is loop over every character in your string, then see what character it is, then sum up the actual value of the letter.  If you want, I can certainly help you with that!

Comment: @rayryeng Well, I don't actually know loops. We haven't learned those yet unfortunately.

Comment: @JessicaMarie - That's fine.  We can do it without loops :)

Comment: @rayryeng Theoretically I can do something along the lines of A = 1, B = 2 etc etc but they's another way supposedly.

Comment: @JessicaMarie - Yes there is.  I'm writing an answer now.  Give me about 10 minutes.